# Launch_arguments doensn't work

Tags: ros2, parameters, launch

I'm trying to run a LiDar driver from my robot bringup launch file, I ofcourse need to give the launch file arguments: hostname and frame id, when running this from CLI it works fine and when I'm trying to pass the arguments with launch_arguments then it doesn't work.

```
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(lidar_dir, "launch", "sick_nav_350.launch.py")
        ),
        launch_arguments={
            "frame_id" : 'lidar',
            'hostname' : '169.254.239.240',
        }.items()
    ),
```

Not sure what goes wrong but I think it has something to do with the implementation of the Lidar launch file where it passes the arguments to another yaml launch file it checks for the usage of := which is only used in CLI

```
ld = LaunchDescription()
sick_scan_pkg_prefix = get_package_share_directory('sick_scan_xd')
launchfile = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-3] # convert "<lidar_name>.launch.py" to "<lidar_name>.launch"
launch_file_path = os.path.join(sick_scan_pkg_prefix, 'launch/' + launchfile) # 'launch/sick_nav_350.launch')
node_arguments=[launch_file_path]

# append optional commandline arguments in name:=value syntax
for arg in sys.argv:
    if len(arg.split(":=")) == 2:
        node_arguments.append(arg)

ROS_DISTRO = os.environ.get('ROS_DISTRO') # i.e. 'eloquent', 'foxy', etc.
if ROS_DISTRO[0] <= "e": # ROS versions eloquent and earlier require "node_executable", ROS foxy and later use "executable"
    node = Node(
        package='sick_scan_xd',
        node_executable='sick_generic_caller',
        output='screen',
        remappings=[ ('/sick_nav_350/scan', '/scan'), ], # remap laserscan messages to topic /scan, required for slam_toolbox
        arguments=node_arguments
    )
```

Any quick solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696569/ros2-how-to-pass-arguments-from-one-launch-file-to-a-child-launch-file/57696570#57696570), you have to declare the launch arguments before to pass it to the launch file.